# How to write a batch file which kill multiple process

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I want a batch file that will kill all of chrome.exe process. I came across with this sample:
taskkill /im chrome.exe

which kill only the first process of chrome.exe that it find. how can I loop it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
taskkill /F /IM <processname.exe> /T
taskkill /F /IM Chrome.exe /T
```

Comment: the /T Terminates the specified process and any child processes which were started by it.